# What is the difference between a non-array var and an array var in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I found that a non-array var can be used as an array var. E.g.:

```
v=11

for i in "${v[@]}"
do
    printf "$i\n"
done

printf "${#v[@]}"

a=(22 33)

for i in "${a[@]}"
do
    printf "$i\n"
done
```

So can I say that **every var is an array var**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, an array parameter is a name with the array attribute set. (Said attribute is set using `declare -a`.) It would be more accurate to say that the array expansion operators treat non-array parameters as if they were arrays parameters with only one index, 0.

Comment: I know that attribute is the difference now. Thanks for your nice explanation!